# Laziness and polymorphic values

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, lazy-evaluation, memoization

(For the following, simplify `Show` and `Read` to

```
class Show a where show :: a -> String
class Read a where read :: String -> a
```

And assume that `read` never fails.)

It's well-known that one can make an existential type of the form

```
data ShowVal where
    ShowVal :: forall a. Show a => a -> ShowVal
```

And then construct a "heterogeneous list" `:: [ShowVal]`, such as

```
l = [ShowVal 4, ShowVal 'Q', ShowVal True]
```

It's also well-known that this is relatively useless, because, instead, one can
just construct a list `:: [String]`, such as

```
l = [show 4, show 'Q', show True]
```

Which is exactly isomorphic (after all, the only thing one can do with a
`ShowVal` is `show` it).

Laziness makes this particularly nice, because for each value in the list, the
result of `show` is memoized automatically, so no `String` is computed more than
once (and `String`s that aren't used aren't computed at all).

A `ShowVal` is equivalent to an existential tuple `exists a. (a -> String, a)`,
where the function is the `Show` dictionary.

A similar construct can be made for `Read`:

```
data ReadVal where
    ReadVal :: (forall a. Read a => a) -> ReadVal
```

Note that, because `read` is polymorphic in its return value, `ReadVal` is
universal rather than existential (which means that we don't really need it at
all, because Haskell has first-class universals; but we'll use it here to
highlight the similaries to `Show`).

We can also make a list `:: [ReadVal]`:

```
l = [ReadVal (read "4"), ReadVal (read "'Q'"), ReadVal (read "True")]
```

Just as with `Show`, a list `:: [ReadVal]` is isomorphic to a list `:: [String]`,
such as

```
l = ["4", "'Q'", "True"]
```

(We can always get the original `String` back with

```
newtype Foo = Foo String
instance Read Foo where read = Foo
```

Because the `Read` type class is open.)

A `ReadVal` is equivalent to a universal function `forall a. (String -> a) -> a`
(a CPS-style representation). Here the `Read` dictionary is supplied by the user
of the `ReadVal` rather than by the producer, because the return value is
polymorphic rather than the argument.

However, in neither of these representations do we get the automatic
memoization that we get in the `String` representation with `Show`. Let's say that
`read` for our type is an expensive operation, so we don't want to compute it
on the same `String` for the same type more than once.

If we had a closed type, we could do something like:

```
data ReadVal = ReadVal { asInt :: Int, asChar :: Char, asBool :: Bool }
```

And then use a value

```
ReadVal { asInt = read s, asChar = read s, asBool = read s }
```

Or something along those lines.

But in this case -- even if we only ever use the `ReadVal` as one type -- the
`String` will be parsed each time the value is used. Is there a simple way to
get memoization while keeping the `ReadVal` polymorphic?

(Getting GHC to do it automatically, similarly to the `Show` case, would be
ideal, if it's somehow possible. A more explicit memoization approach --
perhaps by adding a `Typeable` constraint? -- would also be OK.)

Comment: Your `ReadVal` code makes no sense. You write `ReadVal "4"` as if it has something to do with an integer `4`. Why not discuss `ReadVal 4` instead? Once you realize that `ReadVal 4` is possible, it becomes clear that `[ReadVal]` is not isomorphic to `[String]` at all.

Comment: You're right -- I meant `ReadVal (read "4")`. I should've type-checked before posting... I'll update the question to reflect that, thanks.

(However, `ReadVal 4` is also not valid, because `ReadVal`'s argument needs to be more polymorphic than `Num`.)

Comment: I had in mind a definition like `data ReadVal = forall a. Read a => ReadVal a`, no GADTs. With this definition `ReadVal 4` is possible. I've looked at your definition more closely and I admit that I don't understand it at all.

Comment: My definition is just equivalent to `data ReadVal = ReadVal (forall a. Read a => a)` -- i.e., universal, not existential. It doesn't need a wrapper at all; I just put it there to show the similarity to `ShowVal`.

Comment: An existential `ReadVal` like you described wouldn't be very useful -- there'd be nothing you could do with it. It'd be like a tuple `exists a. (String -> a, a)`.

Comment: Oh I see. So `ReadVal` and `ShowVal` are really asymmetric after all. My bad... BTW you could use `data ShowVal = forall a. Show a => ShowVal a` and `data ReadVal = ReadVal (forall a. Read a => a)`, no GADTs are needed here.

Comment: I'm not sure that you get "memoization" for showing strings (except any that you have introduced yourself by sharing). Certainly `show` does not pack a memo table, so you have no memoization there. If you have a list of "showable" things, useless you use explicit sharing the result of showing will be calculated for every value regardless of whether there are equal (but unshared) values in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the more explicit approach; it requires `Typeable`, because otherwise there'd be nothing to key the memo table on. I based the memoisation code on [uglymemo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uglymemo); there might be a way to get this to work with pure memoisation, but I'm not sure. It's tricky, because you have to construct the table *outside* of the implicit function that any `forall a. (Read a, Typeable a) => ...` creates, otherwise you end up constructing one table per call, which is useless.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Dynamic
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Data.HashMap.Strict (HashMap)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM
import System.IO.Unsafe

data ReadVal where
    ReadVal :: { useReadVal :: forall a. (Read a, Typeable a) => a } -> ReadVal

mkReadVal :: String -> ReadVal
mkReadVal s = unsafePerformIO $ do
    v <- newMVar HM.empty
    return $ ReadVal (readVal v)
  where
    readVal :: (Read a, Typeable a) => MVar (HashMap TypeRep Dynamic) -> a
    readVal v = unsafePerformIO $ do
        m <- readMVar v
        let r = read s  -- not evaluated
        let typeRep = typeOf r
        case HM.lookup typeRep m of
            Nothing -> do
                modifyMVar_ v (return . HM.insert typeRep (toDyn r))
                return r
            Just r' -> return $ fromDyn r' (error "impossible")
```

Answer (score 5):

> Laziness makes this particularly nice, because for each value in the list, the result of show is memoized automatically, so no String is computed more than once (and Strings that aren't used aren't computed at all).

This premise is incorrect. There is no magical memo table under the hood.

Laziness means things that aren't needed, aren't computed. It does not mean that all computed values are shared. You still have to introduce explicit sharing (via a table of your own).

Comment: Right -- I didn't mean anything more than sharing. If you have `s :: String; s =  show x`, you get automatic sharing of the `show` computation if x is used multiple times. You don't get that with `s :: ShowVal; s = ShowVal x`, which is like `exists a. (a -> String, a)`. However, because with `Read` we have a pseudo-function instead of a value, we need actual memoization -- there's no reasonable way of getting sharing, even if the value is only ever used as one type.