# Deserializing an existential data type

Tags: haskell, deserialization, existential-type

I need to write a [`Serialize`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cereal/0.3.5.2/doc/html/Data-Serialize.html) instance for the following data type:

```
data AnyNode = forall n . (Typeable n, Serialize n) => AnyNode n
```

Serializing this is no problem, but I can't implement deserialization, since the compiler has no way to resolve the specific instance of `Serialize n`, since the `n` is isolated from the outer scope.

There's been [a related discussion in 2006](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/nDNOvzXYu12FdvRzXRij). I am now wondering whether any sort of solution or a workaround has arrived today.

Comment: that link to the 2006 discussion is broken. does anybody have a reference to this discussion?

Answer (score 10):

You just tag the type when you serialize, and use a dictionary to untag the type when you deserialize. Here's some pseudocode omitting error checking etc:

```
serialAnyNode (AnyNode x) = serialize (typeOf n, serialize x)

deserialAnyNode s = case deserialize s of
          (typ,bs) -> case typ of
                         "String" -> AnyNode (deserialize bs :: String)
                         "Int" -> AnyNode (deserialize bs :: Int)
                         ....
```

Note that you can only deserialize a *closed* universe of types with your function. With some extra work, you can also deserialize derived types like tuples, maybes and eithers.

But if I were to declare an entirely new type "Gotcha" deriving `Typeable` and `Serialize`, `deserialAnyNode` of course couldn't deal with it without extension.

Comment: In 2006 discussion they came to a similar suggestion. I'll leave the question open in case any better solution appears in the future.

Answer (score 7):

You need to have some kind of centralised "registry" of deserialization functions so you can dispatch on the actual type (extracted from the `Typeable` information).  If all types you want to deserialize are in the same module this is pretty easy to set up.  If they are in multiple modules you need to have one module that has the mapping.

If your collection of types is more dynamic and not easily available at compile time, you can perhaps use the dynamic linking to gain access to the deserializers.  For each type that you want to deserialize you export a C callable function with a name derived from the `Typeable` information (you could use TH to generate these).  Then at runtime, when you want to deserialize a type, generate the same name and the use the dynamic linker to get hold of the address of the function and then an FFI wrapper to get a Haskell callable function.  This is a rather involved process, but it can be wrapped up in a library.  No, sorry, I don't have such a library.

Comment: Yeah, sounds quite involved. Any suggestions on where I could read up on dynamic linking from a perspective of the current problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what you're asking here, exactly. You can certainly pick a particular type `T`, deserialize a `ByteString` to it, and store it in an `AnyNode`. That doesn't do the user of an `AnyNode` much good, though -- you still picked `T`, after all. If it wasn't for the `Typeable` constraint, the user wouldn't even be able to tell what the type is (so let's get rid of the `Typeable` constraint because it makes things messier). Maybe what you want is a universal instead of an existential.

Let's split `Serialize` up into two classes -- call them `Read` and `Show` -- and simplify them a bit (so e.g. `read` can't fail).

So we have

```
class Show a where show :: a -> String
class Read a where read :: String -> a
```

We can make an existential container for a `Show`-able value:

```
data ShowEx where
  ShowEx :: forall a. Show a => a -> ShowEx
-- non-GADT: data ShowEx = forall a. Show a => ShowEx a
```

But of course `ShowEx` is isomorphic to `String`, so there isn't a whole lot point to this. But note that an existential for `Read` is has even less point:

```
data ReadEx where
  ReadEx :: forall a. Read a => a -> ReadEx
-- non-GADT: data ReadEx = forall a. Read a => ReadEx a
```

When I give you a `ReadEx` -- i.e. `∃a. Read a *> a` -- it means that you have a value of some type, and you don't know what the type is, but you can a `String` into another value of the same type. But you can't do anything with it! `read` only *produces* `a`s, but that doesn't do you any good when you don't know what `a` is.

What you might want with `Read` would be a type that lets the caller choose -- i.e., a universal. Something like

```
newtype ReadUn where
  ReadUn :: (forall a. Read a => a) -> ReadUn
-- non-GADT: newtype ReadUn = ReadUn (forall a. Read a => a)
```

(Like `ReadEx`, you could make `ShowUn` -- i.e. `∀a. Show a => a` -- and it would be just as useless.)

Note that `ShowEx` is essentially the argument to `show` -- i.e. `show :: (∃a. Show a *> a) -> String` -- and `ReadUn` is essentially the return value of `read` -- i.e. `read :: String -> (∀a. Read a => a)`.

So what are you asking for, an existential or a universal? You can certainly make something like `∀a. (Show a, Read a) => a` or `∃a. (Show a, Read a) *> a`, but neither does you much good here. The real issue is the quantifier.

(I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10168939/712548) a while ago where I talked about some of this in another context.)

Comment: Hmm, looking at @sclv's answer, it's possible that I just misunderstood the question and am not actually saying anything useful here. But I'll leave my answer up anyway.